Why code from from Metamask documentation does not works - *SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified contentscript.js:1 DOMException..?
From this documentation I got code. I did not changed anything. But despite that I am not able to run Metamask. Error is under the code.
I try to enable Metamask and show account but something get wrong...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const ethereumButton = document.querySelector(".enableEthereumButton");
      const showAccount = document.querySelector(".showAccount");

      if (!ethereumButton) {
        console.error("The element with class 'enableEthereumButton' was not found.");
        return;
      }

      ethereumButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        getAccount();
      });

      async function getAccount() {
        // Check if MetaMask is installed
        if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
          try {
            // Request account access if needed
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            // Get the first account
            const account = accounts[0];
            // Display the account
            showAccount.innerHTML = account;
          } catch (err) {
            if (err.code === 4001) {
              // EIP-1193 userRejectedRequest error
              console.log('Please connect to MetaMask.');
            } else {
              console.error(err);
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log('MetaMask is not installed!');
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Ethereum Account</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Display a connect button and the current account -->
  <button class="enableEthereumButton">Enable Ethereum</button>
  <h2>Account: <span class="showAccount"></span></h2>
  
  
</body>
</html>


But in the console i see (metamask is installed and it is possible to eanble metamask in real hosted web3 sites).
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified contentscript.js:1
DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified
_postMessage file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
_write file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
_handshake file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
l file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
[1]</</< file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
[1]</< file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
[1]< file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
i file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
e file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
<anonymous> file:///C:/Users/mirek/Downloads/pokus1/index.html:1
MetaMask is not installed!


There is error in browser: https://ibb.co/c1fJ4NG

looks like this method is not working anymore:
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined'){}

Normally if metamask was installed, it would inject window.ethereum. check this out on the docs that you shared:
const accounts = await provider // Or window.ethereum if you don't support EIP-6963.

seems like new browsers support EIP-6963. i first checked windows.ethereum and it logged. then I upgraded browser but now it is undefined.

Now from how-to-implement-eip-6963-support-in-your-web-3-dapp

In May 2023, a group of Ethereum wallet developers came together to
establish a new industry standard for connecting with dapps. Before
that, the common practice was for wallets to expose an EIP-1193
provider via the window.ethereum global object in web browsers. This
technique worked well in the early days when users typically owned and
connected to one wallet.
As the ecosystem grew and users started utilizing multiple wallets at
a time, it became difficult for dapp developers to properly manage the
process of detecting what wallet a user was connected to or give users
the option of selecting which wallet to use when many were installed.
In October 2023, this standard, now known as EIP-6963 or Multi-Wallet
Injected Provider Discovery, was accepted. Since then, wallet
developers have started introducing EIP-6963 as the default way of
discovering wallet providers. MetaMask is no exception, as we’ve
ensured that this standard is supported by the MetaMask wallet API and
MetaMask SDK.


Ok, I will hceck it but I would expect that metamask update it on their official site.
